# FPDF A4 Paper not print last row

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm trying to make printing rows on A4 paper, no matter number of rows.
It's important that rows occupy the entire length of A4 paper (297mm).

Example:
So, if I want 4 rows this means that the entire length of the paper A4 is divided by 4
and print so that four rows equally occupy the entire A4 paper.
The problem is that the last row is printed on different paper.
I don't know why?
Does anyone have advice how to solve problem?

Here is my php code:

```
<?php 

require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF {
}

$pdf = new PDF('P', 'mm', array(210, 297));

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);
$pdf->AddPage();
$widhtMM = 210;

$pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
$heightMM = 295;

$pdf->SetXY(0, 0);
$marginTop = 0;

$rows = 7;
$testo = '';

for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {

    $heightMM = 297 / $rows;

    if ($i == 0) {
        $marginTop = 0;
    } else {
        $marginTop += $heightMM;
    }

    $pdf->SetXY(0, $marginTop);
    $pdf->Cell($widhtMM, $heightMM, $heightMM, 'LRTB', 0, 'L', 0);
    $pdf->Ln();

}
$pdf->Output(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need set auto page break before add page (by default is 2cm bottom margin):

```
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);
```

http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setautopagebreak.htm

And it will be better if you change the code a little bit:

```
$heightMM = 297 / $rows;

for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {

    $marginTop = $i*$heightMM;

    $pdf->SetXY(0, $marginTop);
    $pdf->Cell($widhtMM, $heightMM, $heightMM, 'LRTB', 0, 'L', 0);
    $pdf->Ln();

}
```